# Controlar el cerrar la ventana o cambiar de componente

Tags: angular

Tengo un formulario, el cual tiene un botón de guardar cambios, si el formulario es correcto el botón se pone activo, si el formulario no es correcto el botón se pone disabled, quiero que si el botón está activo y el usuario quiere navegar a otro componente o cerrar la pestaña del navegador le alerte ede guardar los cambios

```
<button class="btn btn-block btn-sm btn-success" [disabled]="f.invalid">Guardar cambios</button>
```

Alguna idea? He visto que con Javascript se puede controlar el cerrado de la pestaña, pero nada de los componentes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

vale, estás trabajando con Angular entonces debes usar FormsModule y a su vez en tu formulario usar NgForm. Lo que deberás hacer es validar el formulario algo así:

```
<button class="btn btn-block btn-sm btn-success" [disabled]="f.invalid" (click)="TuFuncion( NombreDelFormulario )">Guardar cambios</button>
```

En el ts:

```
TuFuncion( NombreDelFormulario: NgForm ){
    if( NombreDelFormulario.invalid ){
         console.error( "Algún mensaje de llenar campos" );
    }else{
        if (confirm("¿Realmente deseas salir?")) {
            // Aquí aplicar el router navigate a donde quiere ir.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Mi formulario se llama f, pero me lanza lo siguiente. ERROR TypeError: "f is undefined" sabes que puede ser? Gracias!